# SOQL - Contact Mailing Address

Tags: soql, contact

I am trying to run a SOQL query in the dev console to get resultant records where a Contact's MailingStreet matches a particular LIKE query but can't seem to get any results even when I know it ought to.

Example: MailingStreet is **1234 Fancy Road**

Query: `SELECT MailingStreet FROM Contact WHERE MailingStreet LIKE '%Fancy%'`

However this yields nothing. Is there something special about the built-in MailingAddress compound field or how you need to query it?

If this should be done via SOSL instead, could someone offer an example?

Comment: I just tried your query, it works fine for me. Just keep in mind that a leading wildcard results in a table scan, so if you have a lot of records, you might run in to selectivity problems. Have you tried SOSL?

Comment: MailingAdddress isn't Shield Platform-encrypted by any chance? Normally you'd get an exception if you tried to do a LIKE query on an encrypted field)

Comment: @cropredy I don't believe in my case that it is Shield encrypted since I get no exceptions but I'll have to check with an architect. I was just wondering if I was running the query wrong. Thank you though! sfdcfox I will have to try a SOSL approach or just use workbench to see if I get different results. Much appreciated for the quick feedback

Comment: Seems like it was a connection timeout issue. After awhile things started to return as expected. Thanks all